# iOS Simulator Error: Invalid device state

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

There was some problem with my Macintosh HD so I had to repair permissions using Apple Utility. Post which I started facing this problem that when I run Xcode project, the Simulator doesn't open up. I get this alert saying Error: Invalid Device State.

I know there is another stackoverflow question for the same problem, but none of the solution mentioned worked for me.

Please help!!! I'm in real bad need to get this thing up and running!

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm having Xcode 7.0 running on 10.10.5 OS

Comment: did u restart the xcode ?

Comment: yes I did ! It didn't work :(

Comment: What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list'?

Comment: Every day a new XCode issue - this time it seems unsolvable